# Fastest Way To Retrieve Token Price for Uniswap v2 DEXes

Tags: uniswap

What's the fastest way to retrieve the price? I'm currently using the getAmountsOut function of the router but I feel like for fast moving markets, it's gonna be way too late for me to trade with very low slippage. Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Could you share how you retrieve price info using getAmountsOut? For me it's showing uniswap router2 has no getAmountsOut function. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to create a Trade object to get the amountsOutMin `const trade = new Trade(route, new TokenAmount(tokenA, amountIn), TradeType.EXACT_INPUT);`